# Bump/Displace I just have a hard time comprehending

Tags: normal-map, displacement, bump

I'm trying to get these black & white photos to raise from the wall, distinctly. [PROJECT FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O4w6CxxlXaJBbQbP4Up1zg89o6LENb7T/view?usp=sharing)

I've watched hours of YouTube tutorials. I've fiddled with the settings. I've gotten bump/displace to work when I follow their tutorials using their images but not when I use my own.

I've been puzzled by this for years & I'm frustrated because I just don't understand the mechanics behind it so it doesn't come intuitively.

Sometimes I get it to work but that's just after randomly plugging in nodes & such.

I get it to work on the building texture itself but that texture is procedurally generated

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bump Maps simulate geometry changes based on an image - the light and dark values of an image imply height. Displacement Maps actually change the geometry of the mesh based on the image. Try with Cycles Engine and also share an image of your shader nodes. Another thing to check is if you have Displacement and bump inside the material settings See [THIS](https://youtu.be/hH8hoLuWyVU?t=194)

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems with your scene, hindering good looking displacement :)

1. The building geometry isn't dense enough for proper displacement. Subdivide it more.
2. Displacement node *Scale* is set to 0. That means no displacement.
3. The Door image is not well suited for displacement and is causing artifacts.

<sup>Displacement works reasonably well on a densely subdivided plane</sup>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix your door bump map with the procedural map, use a *MixRGB* in *Multiply* mode, and put the factor at 1, then plug into the *Bump* node:

[image]